# Declaring instance variables and implementing getter methods?

Tags: java, variables, subclass

I am new to Java. Just wanted to ask if I have declared the following instance variables correctly and implemented their getter methods correctly. I only had one instance variable but added two additional instance variables of type int, called numberOfExperiments and powerLevel.

I have written declarations for these instance variables and implemented their associated getter methods. Much Appreciated!

Comment: Can you include ```FlyingObject``` code?

Comment: Yes, it's fine. The `this.` prefix is optional in this case. You can omit it if you want. You probably want a way to set the fields to something other than the default (0). A constructor, or setters.

Comment: I would highly recommend using https://codereview.stackexchange.com for such questions

Answer (score 0):

In your case getters look like correctly implemented.

1. An appropriate naming convention is used (`public <PropertyType> get<PropertyName>();`)
2. Since there's no setter, we can consider the property as read-only.

I would suggest reading through section *8.3 Design Patterns for Properties* of the JavaBeans Spec (https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/spec-136004.html) for additional information.